# How to count occurrences of consecutive 1s by column and take mean by block

Tags: python, pandas

```
x = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(start="2017-1-1", end="2017-1-13"), 
columns="a b c".split())
x.ix[0:2, "a"] = 1
x.ix[5:10, "a"] = 1
x.ix[9:12, "b"] = 1
x.ix[1:3, "c"] = 1
x.ix[5, "c"] = 1

            a   b   c
2017-01-01  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-02  1   NaN 1
2017-01-03  NaN NaN 1
2017-01-04  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-05  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-06  1   NaN 1
2017-01-07  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-08  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-09  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-10  1   1   NaN
2017-01-11  NaN 1   NaN
2017-01-12  NaN 1   NaN
2017-01-13  NaN NaN NaN
```

Given the above dataframe, `x`, I want to return the average of the number of occurences of 1s within each group of `a`, `b`, and `c`. The average for each column is taken over the number of blocks that contains consecutive 1s.

For example, column `a` will output the average of 2 and 5, which is 3.5. We divide it by 2 because there are 2 consecutive 1s between Jan-1 and Jan-2, then 5 consecutive 1s between Jan-06 and Jan-10, 2 blocks of 1s in total. Similarly, for column `b`, we will have 3 because only one consecutive sequence of 1s occur once between Jan-10 and Jan-13. Finally, for column `c`, we will have the average of 2 and 1, which is 1.5.

Expected output of the toy example:

```
a    b  c
3.5  3  1.5
```

Comment: Is this an example or will your dataframe always contain only `1` and `NaN` values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mask` + `apply` with `value_counts`, and finally, find the `mean` of your counts -

```
x.eq(1)\
 .ne(x.eq(1).shift())\
 .cumsum(0)\
 .mask(x.ne(1))\
 .apply(pd.Series.value_counts)\
 .mean(0)

a    3.5
b    3.0
c    1.5
dtype: float64
```

---

**Details**

First, find a list of all consecutive *values* in your dataframe -

```
i = x.eq(1).ne(x.eq(1).shift()).cumsum(0)
i

            a  b  c
2017-01-01  1  1  1
2017-01-02  1  1  2
2017-01-03  2  1  2
2017-01-04  2  1  3
2017-01-05  2  1  3
2017-01-06  3  1  4
2017-01-07  3  1  5
2017-01-08  3  1  5
2017-01-09  3  1  5
2017-01-10  3  2  5
2017-01-11  4  2  5
2017-01-12  4  2  5
2017-01-13  4  3  5
```

Now, keep only those group values whose cells were originally `1` in `x` -

```
j = i.mask(x.ne(1))
j

              a    b    c
2017-01-01  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-02  1.0  NaN  2.0
2017-01-03  NaN  NaN  2.0
2017-01-04  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-05  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-06  3.0  NaN  4.0
2017-01-07  3.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-08  3.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-09  3.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-10  3.0  2.0  NaN
2017-01-11  NaN  2.0  NaN
2017-01-12  NaN  2.0  NaN
2017-01-13  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Now, apply `value_counts` across each column -

```
k = j.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
k


       a    b    c
1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
2.0  NaN  3.0  2.0
3.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
4.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

And just find the column-wise mean -

```
k.mean(0)

a    3.5
b    3.0
c    1.5
dtype: float64
```

As a handy note, if you want to, for example, find the mean counts only for more than `n` consecutive `1`s (say, `n = 1` here), then you can filter on `k`'s index quite easily -

```
k[k.index > 1].mean(0)

a    5.0
b    3.0
c    1.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
x.apply(lambda s: s.groupby(s.ne(1).cumsum()).sum().mean())
```

Output:

```
a    3.5
b    3.0
c    1.5
dtype: float64
```

Apply the lambda function to each column of the dataframe.  The lambda function groups none 1 values together and counts them using sum() then takes the average using mean().

Comment: Not the downvoter, but readers should note that a groupby inside an apply is devilishly slow.

Answer (score 2):

This utilizes `cumsum`, `shift`, and an `xor` mask.

```
b = x.cumsum()  
c = b.shift(-1)
b_masked = b[b.isnull() ^ c.isnull()]

b_masked.max() / b_masked.count()

a    3.5
b    3.0
c    1.5
dtype: float64
```

First do `b = x.cumsum()`

```
    a       b       c
0   1.0     NaN     NaN
1   2.0     NaN     1.0
2   NaN     NaN     2.0
3   NaN     NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN     NaN
5   3.0     NaN     3.0
6   4.0     NaN     NaN
7   5.0     NaN     NaN
8   6.0     NaN     NaN
9   7.0     1.0     NaN
10  NaN     2.0     NaN
11  NaN     3.0     NaN
12  NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Then, shift `b` upward: `c = b.shift(-1)`. Then, we create a xor mask with `b.isnull() ^ c.isnull()`. This mask will only keep one value per consecutive ones. Note that it seems that it will create an extra `True` at the end. But since we put it back to `b`, where in the place it is NaN, it will not generate new elements. We use an example to illustrate

```
 b   c   b.isnull() ^ c.isnull()    b[b.isnull() ^ c.isnull()]
NaN  1         True                          NaN
 1   2         False                         NaN
 2  NaN        True                          2
NaN NaN        False                         NaN
```

Real big `b[b.isnull() ^ c.isnull()]` looks like

```
    a       b        c
0   NaN     NaN     NaN
1   2.0     NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     2.0
3   NaN     NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN     NaN
5   NaN     NaN     3.0
6   NaN     NaN     NaN
7   NaN     NaN     NaN
8   NaN     NaN     NaN
9   7.0     NaN     NaN
10  NaN     NaN     NaN
11  NaN     3.0     NaN
12  NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Because we did `cumsum` in the first place, we only need the maximum and the number of non-NaN in each column to calculate the mean.

Thus, we do `b[b.isnull() ^ c.isnull()].max() / b[b.isnull() ^ c.isnull()].count()`

Answer (score 0):

you could use regex:

```
import re

p = r'1+'

counts = {
    c: np.mean(
        [len(x) for x in re.findall(p, ''.join(map(str, x[c].values)))]
        )
    for c in ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

This method works because the columns here could be thought as expressions in a language with alphabet {`1`, `nan`}. `1+` matches all groups of adjacent 1s and `re.findall` returns a list of strings. Then, it is necessary to calculate the mean of the lengths of each string.